# Modifying to.period to include "semi-annual"

Tags: r, xts

I would like to calculate semi-annual aggregations of an xts object. I thought I could use `to.period`, but the output is still an xts with 4 data points per year whereas I would like only two.

```
data(edhec, package="PerformanceAnalytics")
xts::to.period(edhec[,1],period="quarters",k=2,OHLC=FALSE)
```

I would like to modify this `to.period` function to include a semi-annual output. Any suggestions? The code is a little too complex for me. I think it must have something to do with `endpoints` which is a second function in the xts package.

```
function (x, period = "months", k = 1, indexAt = NULL, name = NULL, 
OHLC = TRUE, ...) 
{
    if (missing(name)) 
        name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    xo <- x
    x <- try.xts(x)
    if (NROW(x) == 0 || NCOL(x) == 0) 
        stop(sQuote("x"), " contains no data")
    if (any(is.na(x))) {
        x <- na.omit(x)
        warning("missing values removed from data")
    }
    if (!OHLC) {
        xx <- x[endpoints(x, period, k), ]
    }
    else {
        if (!is.null(indexAt)) {
            index_at <- switch(indexAt, startof = TRUE, endof = FALSE, 
                FALSE)
        }
        else index_at <- FALSE
        cnames <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")
        if (has.Vo(x)) 
            cnames <- c(cnames, "Volume")
        if (has.Ad(x) && is.OHLC(x)) 
            cnames <- c(cnames, "Adjusted")
        cnames <- paste(name, cnames, sep = ".")
        if (is.null(name)) 
            cnames <- NULL
        xx <- .Call("toPeriod", x, endpoints(x, period, k), has.Vo(x), 
            has.Vo(x, which = TRUE), has.Ad(x) && is.OHLC(x), 
            index_at, cnames, PACKAGE = "xts")
    }
    if (!is.null(indexAt)) {
        if (indexAt == "yearmon" || indexAt == "yearqtr") 
            indexClass(xx) <- indexAt
        if (indexAt == "firstof") {
            ix <- as.POSIXlt(c(.index(xx)), tz = indexTZ(xx))
            if (period %in% c("years", "months", "quarters", 
                "days")) 
                index(xx) <- firstof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
                  1)
            else index(xx) <- firstof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
                1, ix$mday, ix$hour, ix$min, ix$sec)
        }
        if (indexAt == "lastof") {
        ix <- as.POSIXlt(c(.index(xx)), tz = indexTZ(xx))
            if (period %in% c("years", "months", "quarters", 
                "days")) 
                index(xx) <- as.Date(lastof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
                  1))
            else index(xx) <- lastof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
                1, ix$mday, ix$hour, ix$min, ix$sec)
        }
    }
    reclass(xx, xo)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify the `to.period` source?  Seems like you should be able to use `to.period(x, "quarters", 2)`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't provide the desired output. it creates an xts object that is still in a quarterly format:
`temp
                         data
1965-01-31         1
1965-02-28         1
1965-03-31         1
1965-04-30         1
1965-05-31         1
1965-06-30         1
1965-07-31         1
1965-08-31         1
1965-09-30         1
1965-10-31         1
1965-11-30         1
1965-12-31         1`

`to.period(temp,period="quarters",k=2,OHLC=FALSE)
           10006.Adjusted
1965-03-31        1
1965-06-30        1
1965-09-30        1
1965-12-31        1`
@JoshuaUlrich

Comment: For a reproducible example:
'data(edhec)'
'to.period(edhec[,1],period="quarters",k=2,OHLC=FALSE)'

The output still creates an xts with 4 data points per year whereas I would like only two. But I guess I can take every other data point with more code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in `xts::endpoints()`. In the case of `period = "months"` and `k > 1`, `endpoints()` makes this adjustment:

```
if (k > 1) ep[seq(1, length(ep), k)] else ep
```

And `to.period()` with `OHLC = FALSE` just subsets the input object by the output of `endpoints()`.  So it is equivalent to:

```
data(edhec, package="PerformanceAnalytics")
ep <- endpoints(edhec[,1], "quarters", 2)
edhec[ep, 2]
```

See if the fix for this bug is as simple as adding the same adjustment as when `period = "months"`:

```
data(edhec, package="PerformanceAnalytics")
ep <- endpoints(edhec[,1], "quarters", 1)
ep <- ep[seq(1, length(ep), 2)]
edhec[ep, 2]
```